# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1)

Tags: spring, schema, xsd-validation

I have a project that runs under a firewall. It uses cxf-core-3.4.4 jar that has cxf.xml file and it has xsd schema for spring-beans.

when executing the java application, running into below exception.

```
2023-09-21 18:50:03,766 [main] WARN  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
.
.
.
.

    Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext/cxf-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 23 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.


    .
    .
    .
    .Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
    Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext/cxf-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 23 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 242; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
```

from the above stack trace, it appears its trying to connect to springframework site to get the xsd but its not able to since its behind firewall.

I have verified spring.schema file has entry for this xsd pointing to the /factory/xml.. folder to the xsd file and the file exists.

how to solve this issue given that both are third party jars.